# Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU on Windows

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I installed the latest versions of cordova and android studio and did all the necessary configurations. But now it gives me a problem when I give the command "cordova emulate android" giving me the following error "Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU on Windows" that I can't solve.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable the virtualization in your BIOS.

[image]

[image]